# Kicking off a script and moving on to start another

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to remotely deploy some software and I have a few batch scripts to help this process along.  The basics of my process is to have a text list that `scriptA` goes through, `scriptA` copies the necessary files to the target PCs (retrieved from the list) and launches `ScriptB`.  The theory would then be that it would move on to the next PC in the list as soon as ScriptB launches and doesn't wait for ScriptB to finish before moving on.  The basics of what I have are below:

`ScriptA`:

```
Set /P List= Please enter the list name
Set /P Name= Please enter your username
FOR /F %%A IN (%LIST%) DO (
MKDIR \\%%A\C$\Temp\Install
XCOPY "\\share\necessary files" "\\%%A\C$\Temp\Install"
PSEXEC \\%%A -u DOMAIN\%NAME% -e "\\%%A\C$\Temp\Install\scriptB.bat"
)
```

`ScriptB` just runs the installer and cleans up after itself.

Like I said, the goal would be that once `scriptA` has finished copying over files and gets things kicked off, it would move on to the next PC on the list.  I've confirmed that everything works as is right now (so please ignore any random things that wouldn't work in the pseudocode above) it just takes forever because it waits for the installation to finish before moving on.

EDIT:

I realized I had the wrong files shown as being copied.  What was originally listed as 'install.bat' should have been scriptB.  I apologize, it has been very hard to try to get my question across as I'm having a very hard time describing the problem.

Per Request, here is how I was using start:

ScriptA:

```
START PSECEC \\%%A -u DOMAIN\%NAME% -e "\\%%A\C$\Temp\Install\ScriptB.bat"
```

It worked to start ScriptB in a new window, but what I'm really trying to have as the final product is:

- scriptA gets prompts for the list of PC names
- scriptA pulls the first name from the list and copies over the install files from a     network share, including scriptB and puts them in \temp\install
- scriptA kicks off scriptB on the PC it just copied files to.
- While scriptB is running, scriptA moves on and copies the files to the next PC on the list and kicks of the next copy of scriptB
- repeat until the whole list of PCs is completed.

I hope this helps to clarify things, and again, I apologize for the confusion.  I have all of the steps listed above working as I would hope, the only thing that isn't working is that I can't get scriptA to kick off scriptB without pausing scriptA to wait for scriptB to finish and what I would like to have happen is that it moves on without waiting (so that I could start this script at the end of the day and it would continue installing at night until it finished the list of PCs).

Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `START` command to launch a command without waiting for it to end before moving on. Note that this will execute the specified command in a newly created command prompt, not in the same command prompt process.

Be aware though that if the path to your executable/batch file contains spaces, you must specify an empty string argument as the first argument. Example:

```
START "" "C:\Path with spaces\My other script.bat"
```

This is due to the fact that if the first arguments is surrounded by quotes, it is considered as being the title of the new command prompt that is launched to execute your new process. Specifying an empty argument (or the title you'd like to use for that matter) will work around this situation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Unfortunately, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  My idea with this is to be able to start this script running at night before I leave and after my users have left, and have the script run through the installations while everyone is away.  I added the start command and it DID allow for other processes to begin, but once it opened the new CMD window, it paused the original.  Any ideas on how I could kick off scriptB without pausing ScriptA?

Comment: @TheLegNBass I just tested the `START` command, and it doesn't pause the calling script while executing the second script. Maybe with some `ECHO` you could debug and see which command waits for the other script to end before proceeding? Or maybe there's can be only one `PSEXEC` command at a time?

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  There was a pause that I must've overlooked from when I was troubleshooting that was halting things up.  I've fixed it now and it's working.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The further we are away from the actual problem, the less able we are to help. The more general the question, the more vague the response.

We're pointlessly mapping from "ScriptB" to "Install.bat" and you've claimed to have added the start command but not shown us where you've used it.

Using your original script, changing

```
PSEXEC \\%%A -u DOMAIN\%NAME% -e "\\%%A\C$\Temp\Install.bat"
```

to

```
start "installing on %%A" PSEXEC \\%%A -u DOMAIN\%NAME% -e "\\%%A\C$\Temp\Install.bat"
```

should solve the problem - but no guarantees.

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness of my question, I've edited it to try to make things more clear.  Thank you for your help and I hope my edits have helped to straighten things out some.